# How to target an element outside map by clicking on google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

I have a group of articles that are linked to markers on a google map. I'm using Laravel 5 and the google maps API. When I click on an article it's information div expands and a google maps infowindow is also expanded.

What I want to do is click on a google maps marker and expand the article information div. ie I want it to work *both ways.*

The articles are dynamically created.

Here's the relevant part of my google maps code:

```
    var barID = [
    @foreach($articles as $article)
    {{$article->id}},
    @endforeach
    ];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    infoWindowContent[i] = getInfoWindowDetails(locations[i]);
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        id: barID[i],
        icon: 'images/happymarker.png'
    });
  var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      map: map, etc..
    });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infoBubble.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
          infoBubble.open(map, marker);
          map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
          map.setZoom(17);
        }
      })(marker, i));
      markers.push(marker);
}
// SHOW MORE INFO BUTTON TRIGGERS INFOWINDOW/MARKER
    function myClick(id){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    }
```

THIS IS MY ATTEMPT -but it doesn't work.

```
marker.addListener('click', function(theID) {

$(".descriptionTextContainer" + theID).show();  

      });
```

THE MARKUP / ARTICLES (outside of the map container). I've added an id to all the articles so it will be class="descriptionTextContainer 24" -ie all the different text containers will have unique ids in their classes.

```
 <article class="barContainer mix category-<?php echo $article->id; ?>" data-rating="<?php echo $article->rating; ?>" data-distance="<?php echo $article->distance; ?>">
 $something = $articles->lists('id'); 
                    $artID = $article->id;  
                    $key= $something->search($artID); ?>   

// THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I CLICK TO SHOW THE 'descriptionTextContainer'               
  <div class="resultsTitle showMoreDetails" onclick="myClick(<?php echo $key; ?>);">
    <div class="barTitleContainer"><h2>{{$article->title}}</h2></div>
  </div>           
  <div class="descriptionTextContainer <?php echo $key; ?>">            
// THIS IS HIDDEN TILL THE MARKER OR THE 'ShowMoreDetails' is clicked                  
  </div>
</article>
```

Here's [the site](https://gethappy.co.nz/articles?q=Wellington%2C%20New%20Zealand&lat=-41.2864603&lng=174.77623600000004&distance=5) as it's working atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a bind on your marker : you can just open the div by adding a line on id as you have stored the article id in marker.id

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infoBubble.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
      infoBubble.open(map, marker);
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(17);
      // Add this line
      $(".descriptionTextContainer" + marker.id).show(); 
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything. If I console.log(marker.id) it just shows an array of all the IDs and not the particular ID I'm trying to target. Thoughts?

Comment: I seem to be able to get the ID I want if I console.log(marker.barID[i]) inside that gmaps listener. But it doesn't matter what I put before [i] I always get the same error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'the ID i'm looking for' of undefined"

Comment: Before you create the marker, on `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        id: barID[i],
        icon: 'images/happymarker.png'
    });`, can you `console.log(barID[i]) ;` ? There must be a problem here... if you declare id:barId[i] then marker.id is the id you need, don't understand why you got the whole array in the listener. You can also add articleId : barID[i] instead of id : barID[i] in your creation of marker, just to be sure the key is used only for this.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Cheers. $(".descriptionTextContainer" + "." + marker.articleID).show();

Comment: Glad it works ;) you can mark the question as answered.